# Can't run hello world in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to learn PL/SQL, but I cannot run a basic script. At this point I feel there is not a syntax issue, but something basic I'm missing.

```
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
END
```

When I run it I get an error saying

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
END
```

When I run the script I get an error saying:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

If you know what I might be missing let me know.

Comment: do you create a function or storeprocedure  for those begin end?

Comment: If this is an anonymous PL/LSQL block in an SQL window of PL/SQL Developer, then Rajesh's answer below should resolve your issue. With this IDE, in stored procedure window (I.e., not an SQL window) you don't need that trailing terminator `/` but you do need the `END;`'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a semicolon and "/" at the end, before you run the script.

```
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
END;
/
```

Don't forget to "`set serveroutput on`" to see the actual output.

Comment: The `set serveroutput on` really helps